# Angular Model From Server

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I just can't get my head wrapped around this idea, any help would be greatly appreciated.

A lot of conversations state the Model should come from the server via restful web services.  I've been using $http in a factory.  This makes sense to me "if" there is data present.  If you load a screen and the user or whatever is new then you get a blank JSON value.  For complex data (relationships) you get those items with a value but other properties are left off.

So what am I missing here, how can the model come from the server consistently?

Answer (score 1):

It's useful to think of your model as both a server model and a client model. The server model should be your true model or "source of truth", and the client model is a working model or "mimic" that should behave as a local copy of the server model.

For the model to "come from the server consistently", you have to ensure that any changes to the client model get validated by the server side.  Meaning that when any change requests to the model -- such as create, remove, update, or delete (crud) -- get sent as requests to the server, and then the resulting changed data model gets returned to the client model so it can be updated.

Comment: So if you have a web service that holds the true model (I'm using asp.net web api 2), then do I need to create separate javascript objects that match the server?  I have a parent table with 4 child tables.  I then have to make sure any structural changes to the web api model need to be replicated in the client java script objects?  Or can the server somehow return the model in the first place, independent of if a record exists, such as a new record.

Comment: Yes, you should SELECTIVELY create a client side model that matches the server model ONLY for non-sensitive information that you want EXPOSED to the client.  If any structural changes occur to the server model, then the client model and any impacted model services will need to be refactored.  OR if using the approach where the server returns the model each time, you can just use that JSON and assign it directly to an object bound to $scope within the controller for use.

Comment: Thank you David.  This is really helpful.  So, I will create client side models if need be, but you also mention returning the model from the server, is there any examples of how to do this?  I just can't find one.  Again, I have a restful asp.net web api with get(id), put, post.  But if there is no record available, you get an empty JSON object or pre-defined error.  If there was any examples I would be thrilled, I haven't found anything anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of standard HTTP status codes as a mechanism to provide results to the client:

for example, your service could return an HTTP code of 204 to indicate that the server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content.